# How to decrypt the my 1Password Vault without using the 1Password App?

Tags: aes, decryption

I would like to know, how someone can decrypt his 1Password Vault without using the 1Password app. It should be feasible. Right?

In a nutshel,

My Master Password is the only "AES key" that my logins/passwords/notes/etc in the Vault are encrypted by the 1Password app. So, in this case, my Master Password + the decrypting algorithm can decrypt them from scratch. Am I right?

[Agile Keychain Design](https://help.agilebits.com/1Password3/agile_keychain_design.html)

[Question about .js and .keys files](https://discussions.agilebits.com/discussion/11353/contents-js-and-1password-keys)

Comment: this might be a question for 1password support

Comment: @schroeder why ? The question can be so so deep. If the "for scratch" decryption is working from an already encypted file by 1Password, it can be the same with any other encrypting app or password manager which uses only the Master key as a encryption key and not any random-salt or any other technic to hard the encryption files.

Comment: @greg It would depend on the specific format that each app used. For example, one might store the raw AES output, one might wrap it in a metadata later, one might base 64 encode after combining with a checksum. That processing may render a generic approach unusable